# Difference between localtime and clock

Tags: sles, timezone

`/etc/localtime` is a symlink.

`/etc/sysconfig/clock` is a config file.

**Q:** What is the difference between them? Each could store timezone setting.

Using SLES.

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/sysconfig/clock` is a config file used to symlink /etc/localtime correctly. If you run `rpm -q --scripts timezone` you can see the timezone package will automatically create that symlink for you if it isn't there.

I can tell you in the Red Hat land of stuff, it doesn't use a symlink and some other packages (like glibc) will use the setting in `/etc/sysconfig/clock` to copy the appropriate `/usr/share/zone/foo/bar` file to `/etc/localtime` . I'm not sure if Suse has anything similar.